# opscode Chef: Issue while bootstrapping a node

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I am trying to bootstrap a node using the knife command and got below error.

command :

```
knife bootstrap <hostname> --sudo -x <username>  -N <Nodename> -E <env> --bootstrap-proxy <proxy>

Error : Connecting to <hostname>
ERROR: Net::SSH::Disconnect: connection closed by remote host
```

So, I directly logged in on node and installed the chef rpm and generated the client.rb and copied personal cert validator.pem to node and when I run the chef-client I get below error.

```
[root@test bin]# chef-client
Starting Chef Client, version 11.8.0
[2014-12-19T15:58:03+11:00] ERROR: SSL Validation failure connecting to host: Chef_server - SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A

================================================================================
Chef encountered an error attempting to load the node data for "test_DR"
================================================================================


Unexpected Error:
-----------------
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A


[2014-12-19T15:58:03+11:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated
[2014-12-19T15:58:03+11:00] ERROR: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
[2014-12-19T15:58:03+11:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
[root@test bin]#
```

Comment: Not related to the answer, but please have a tad more patience on IRC. You had already left by the time I went to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first error means your workstation is having issues SSH'ing to the target. The second error means you have an invalid TLS certificate on your Chef server. See https://www.chef.io/blog/2014/12/12/chef-12-fix-untrusted-self-signed-certificates/ for instructions on fixing the second issue. To fix the first you'll have to check things like firewall rules and other possible connection issues. You seem to be using a proxy, so ensure that is working correctly.